# Interpretation of Rotation Vector Measurements

Tags: sensor, math, android

I use android devices (Xiaomi Mi9-SE (Android 10) & Huawei P10 (Android 9)) to collect movement data from bicycle rides. Hereby, I am measuring i.a the Rotation Vector which describes the rotation of the smartphone to the earth's reference frame (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent#sensor.type_rotation_vector:).

The sensor returns four values, which represent the rotation as a quaternion (w,x,y,z).

In my experiment I recorded a bike ride with two smartphones, which were glued to each other in the same alignment. When I plot the returned values from the Rotation Sensors numerically, they seem to be similar in some phases and dissimilar in others (cf. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pq1Kk.png), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qlLy.png))

However, when in a dissimilar phase (e.g. ~22:12:30h), it seems like the rotations are still somehow the same, but the axis are swapped. I plotted two corresponding rotations (cf. [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXYdm.png), [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mQUS.png)). If the x and y axis were swapped and mirrored on the new y, the rotation would become similar.
I wonder if this behavior is due to inaccurate/bad sensors or whether I missed something working with quaternions.

Would be really great if someone could tell me, if/where I miss a point here.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Which smartphones did you use? Are they the same model? Same OS?

Comment: I used Xiaomi Mi-9 SE (Android 10) and Huawei P10 (Android 9). I edited the question.

Comment: Perhaps the sensors are mounted in different orientations in different phones?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. However, the measurements are similar in certain phases. So it seems like one sensor switches orientations somewhen during the record. I would love to understand why/when this happens